# BindingSource CurrentChanged/PositionChanged old item

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, bindingsource

Is there a way to get a notification before `Current` of a `BindingSource` changes in Windows Forms, including the old item?

I'd like to save the old element before navigating away. `CurrentChanged` and `PositionChanges` both are `EventHandler` events and do not provide a reference to the old item.

It is not that important to get notified *before* the position changes, but it is critical to get the old item.

Cheers
Matthias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

store it yourself ...

everytime `Current` changes you are notified by the event...

if you have a reference that is updated at the end of your eventhandler (store reference to current item) you can look at this reference when the event handler runs again ... when you look at it before it is updated, it will refer to the old item

Comment: OK, thanks, I'll do that. I was wondering if there was a neat way to get around this.